# Two linear transformations with the same kernel and image

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T$ and $L$ linear operators with vector space $V$ such that $Im(T)=Im(L)$ and $Ker(T)=Ker(L)$ show that $L = T$

Since they are linear operators

$$T:V\to V \mbox{ and } L:V\to V$$

Base is $ \{\alpha_{1},\cdots,\alpha_{r}\} $ of $Ker(T)$ base completed of $V$ wiht $ \{\alpha_{r+1},\cdots,\alpha_{n}\} $ and $ \{T\alpha_{r+1},\cdots,T\alpha_{n}\} $ is base of $Im(T)$ but I can not think like finding equality

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just not true as stated. Take two maps $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, the first being multiplication by 1 and the second being multiplication by 2. The maps have the same kernel $\{0\}$ and the same image $\mathbb{R}$ but are clearly not the same map.

Answer (score 2):

Take an  invertible linear transformation from $V$ to $V$. The kernal is $\{0\}$ and image is $V$. So if you can find two distinct inverible linear transformations you can see that your question is wrong.

One can also give examples with two non-invertible ones having same kernel and image.

Let $L$ be a non-invertible transformation with image $W$. Take a basis of $W$, extend it to a basis of $V$. Let $T$ be any  permutation  that pemutes this basis by sending $W$-basis vectors among itself, and the others among itself. Now $L$ and  $L\circ T$ both are non-invertible with same kernel and image.